# How do I convert from binary to decimal in java (using android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an android app and one of the components of the app is designed to take a number in binary and convert it to decimal. Every time I run it, it crashes.

```
public void Button0Clicked(View v)
{
        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (firstType == true)
    {
        myText.setText("");
        firstType = false;
    }
    myText.setText(myText.getText() + "0");

}
public void Button1Clicked(View v)
{
        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (firstType == true)
        {
            myText.setText("");
            firstType = false;
        }
        myText.setText(myText.getText() + "1");
}
public void Conversion(View view)
{
        TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(myText.getText().toString(),2);
        TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        result.setText(decimalValue);

}
```

I've narrowed the problem down to some problem with the Integer.parseint() function, is my implementation wrong?

Stack Trace

```
07-04 09:43:17.806  29832-29832/com.example.jay.myapplication2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jay.myapplication2, PID: 29832
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x271a
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
            at com.example.jay.myapplication2.MyActivity.Conversion(MyActivity.java:66)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: What's the error when it crashes? Is it throwing an exception? What is it?

Comment: In Logcat it says  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity"

Comment: Can you please add a stack trace using logcat to the question.

Comment: Where is line 66 of MainActivity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
 result.setText(decimalValue); // int param
```

To:

```
 result.setText(Integer.toString(decimalValue)); // string param
```

And it will work just fine.

Function View.setText() is overloaded for String and integer type of parameter.

When the compiler detected an integer param, as is your case, it attempts to find a 
String resource by that ID.

Remember - never pass an integer value to setText() unless it is a resource ID.

Comment: I'd suggest using `Integer.toString(decimalValue)` rather than `"" + decimalValue`; it's clearer at a glance what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass integer to the TextView setText method. Convert it to String and there you go.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ pass an integer to `setText`; unfortunately for OP, when you do this it is interpreted as a string resource ID.